# How can junk letters be removed from a document with sed?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have a list which is an output from a media program actually and i want to remove all the junk so i can use that list to my Zenity script but involves alot of sed commands in one string which is the way i prefer im open any suggestion that involves only sed.

I will explain exactly what i'm trying to succeed:

The actual list is **List.txt:**
[image]
The * is just hex 1b

```
*line here is not needed*
*[1m0  *[22m : *[35mThis has SPACES inside, Must be DOTS!*[39m : *[34m123.123ABCD*[39m
*[1m1  *[22m : *[35mThis-DONT-have(SPACES)-inside*[39m : *[34m900.578CD*[39m
*[1m2  *[22m : *[35mThis SPACE!!! inside, # Must be DOTS!*[39m : *[34m9K99123AD*[39m
*[1m3  *[22m : *[35mSPACES *Must* be DOTS!*[39m : *[34mAB*[39m
*[1m4  *[22m : *[35mMust[be] [DOTS] !*[39m : *[34m12.AZZZ*[39m
*[1m5  *[22m : *[35mSPACES ~DOTS!*[39m : *[34m654KK45*[39m
```

This is my sed equation:

```
cat ~/List.txt | sed -e 1d -e 's/\x1b\[1m//g' -e 's/\x1b\[22m : \x1b\[35m/|---|/g' -e 's/\x1b\[39m : /|---| /g' -e 's/.|---|*//' -e 's/|---|*//' -e 's/\x1b*\[34m/(/g' -e 's/\x1b\[39m/)/g' -e 's/^/FALSE /' -e '0,/FALSE /s//TRUE /' > sedList.txt
```

This is the **sedList.txt** which has spaces between the words:

```
TRUE 0 This has SPACES inside, Must be DOTS! (123.123ABCD)
FALSE 1 This-DONT-have(SPACES)-inside (900.578CD)
FALSE 2 This SPACE!!! inside, # Must be DOTS! (9K99123AD)
FALSE 3 SPACES *Must* be DOTS! (AB)
FALSE 4 Must[be] [DOTS] ! (12.AZZZ)
FALSE 5 SPACES ~DOTS! (654KK45)
```

I want to replace those spaces with dots in the specific location (**not everything**) so the sedList.txt looks **exacly** like this:

```
TRUE 0 This.has.SPACES.inside,.Must.be.DOTS! (123.123ABCD)
FALSE 1 This-DONT-have(SPACES)-inside (900.578CD)
FALSE 2 This.SPACE!!!.inside,.#.Must.be.DOTS! (9K99123AD)
FALSE 3 SPACES.*Must*.be.DOTS! (AB)
FALSE 4 Must[be].[DOTS].! (12.AZZZ)
FALSE 5 SPACES.~DOTS! (654KK45)
```

So what is missing from my sed equation should i add something?

Comment: If I understand right, you're already able to remove the ESC characters (u+1b) and all the related noise, and now you need to also replace the spaces with dots, yes? I ask cause this is a really complicated question as-is. It might be easier if you gave an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Somewhat related (on [unix.se]): [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you were almost there, I just replaced all spaces by dots first.

```
sed -e 1d \
        -e 's/\s/./g' \
        -e 's/x1b\[1m0/TRUE 0/g' \
        -e 's/x1b\[1m/FALSE /g' \
        -e 's/\.\./ /g' \
        -e 's/\!x1b\[39m/\!/g' \
        -e 's/x1b\[34m/\(/g' \
        -e 's/x1b\[39m/\)/g' \
        -e 's/x1b\[22m\.\:\.x1b\[35m//g' \
        -e 's/\.\./\./g' \
        -e 's/\.\:\./ /g' \
~/List.txt > SEDList.txt
```

Comment: It get's all mash up with dots and hexes please see my examples above see SEDList.txt  how should look

Comment: @GoldHaloWings I just tested this and it works perfectly. You might need to replace the `x1b`s in this answer with `\x1b`.

Comment: @wjandrea What the heck? When i tested with zenity with an actual output list (from the media program) it didn't work and then i test it with the List.txt it worked i don't get this, so is working but is not wotking with the actual output i guess?

Comment: @J. Starnes SED  string working only with List.txt not with actual output your answer is correct thank you.

Comment: @J. Starnes im sure it got to do with the fact that x1b must be /\x1b pls take a look above my bad  sed equation plus  a posted  a picture an example of the text to get the idea

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask for `sed`:

```
sed -re 1d \
  -e 's/\x1b\[[0-9]+m//g' \
  -e 'y/ /./' \
  -e 's/^([0-9]+)\.*:\./FALSE \1 /'\
  -e 's/\.:\.(.*)/ (\1)/'\
  -e '1s/FALSE/TRUE/'
```

Answer (score 1):

This one produces the desired output:

```
sed '1d;s/\x1b\[[0-9]*m//g;s/  *: /\n/g;y/ /./;s/^/FALSE /;2s/FALSE/TRUE/;s/$/)/;s/\n/ /;s// (/' yourfile
```

My hints for you:

- First of all: Don't `cat` and pipe to `sed`. Rather give the filename as argument to `sed`.
- Next, handle all Escape-sequences at once with a regular expression like `\x1b\[[0-9]*m` to simplify your script
- Avoid "magical" patterns like your `|---|`. With GNU `sed` you can use newline instead. This is unique and easy to handle.

Commented version:

```
sed '1d;                # drop the first line
     s/\x1b\[[0-9]*m//g;# remove all esc sequences
     s/  *: /\n/g;      # replace the colons with spaces by newlines
     y/ /./;            # replace the spaces with dots
     s/^/FALSE /;       # add the `FALSE` to the beginning
     2s/FALSE/TRUE/;    # except for the second line
     s// (/;            # first separator becomes space
     s/$/)/;            # second becomes space with (
     s/\n/ /;           # finally the trailing )' yourfile
```

Comment: Can SED strings be syntaxed like this;
echo "$TheList" | sed -e ... -e ... -e

In more detail how the list is syntaxed in my script:
VAR=$(zenity ... ... ... $(echo "$TheList" | sed -e ... -e ... -e))

Comment: That's not a question of `sed`, but of escaping inside `$(...)`

Answer (score 0):

While the following is not as fast as a single `sed` call, it adds flexibility.

```
sed \
    -e 1d  \
    -re 's/\x1b\[[0-9]+m//g' \
    -e 's/:/ /g' List.txt |
awk '{
    if ($1=="0")
        {printf("TRUE "$1" "); for (i=2; i<=(NF-1); i++) printf("%s%s",".",$i); printf(" ("$NF")\n")}
    else
        {printf("FALSE "$1" "); for (i=2; i<=(NF-1); i++) printf("%s%s",".",$i); printf(" ("$NF")\n")}
    }' |
sed 's/ \./ /g' > SEDList.txt
```

As a single line sutible for use in a script.

```
"$( sed -e 1d -re 's/\x1b\[[0-9]+m//g' -e 's/:/ /g' "$TheList" | awk '{ if ($1=="0") {printf("TRUE "$1" "); for (i=2; i<=(NF-1); i++) printf("%s%s",".",$i); printf(" ("$NF")\n")} else {printf("FALSE "$1" "); for (i=2; i<=(NF-1); i++) printf("%s%s",".",$i); printf(" ("$NF")\n")} }' | sed 's/ \./ /g' )"
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this question as composed of 2 problems: (1) remove the ansi-seq and (2) adjust 
and clean the format. The first part obfuscates the second.

Here a give just a partial answer: I suggest  the use of `ansifilter` for an initial cleaning of ansi-sequences:

```
ansifilter ~/List.txt | ...
```